# Create C/C++ language binding for existing ADA library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ada, gnat

I have an existing library in Ada (https://github.com/OpenAADL/ocarina) which I am interested in using from a C++ context.

It seems that in previous versions of GNAT, there was a [generator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Running-the-C-Header-Generator.html), that would create c headers for existing Ada code.

For current versions of GNAT I could only find the section on [mixed language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gnat_ugn/Building-Mixed-Ada-and-C_002b_002b-Programs.html#Building-Mixed-Ada-and-C_002b_002b-Programs) programming. This gives me an idea, how to make a library that can be interfaced, by using pragmas to make the Ada code conform to a C abi, but I could not find a hint on how to do this for an existing library, which I do not want to modify.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but couldn't you write a wrapper library in Ada with a C-style API?

Comment: I think Keith has it. Normally you would "export" the Ada code, with `Convention => C` but that requires either  modifying the library, or as Keith says, writing a (trivial) wrapper over it. (The exported code may simply "rename" the library code, instead of calling it, if the library is in source form. However if it's precompiled, the wrapper probably needs to call it, to provide the "convention C" ABI.

Comment: I had hoped to avoid manually writing a wrapper over the api, which is rather large. But if its the way to go...

Comment: For suitable values of "rather large" you may find a simple Python script (or Ada program) will do 90% of the work and pay back the time spent writing it. Unfortunately I don't know how you would specify "convention Ada" to the C code if you wanted to call the library directly from C, though you might search on "__stdcall" and its friends if you want to find a (probably compiler-specific) approach.

Comment: The generator you refer to is present in both GNAT GPL 2016 and FSF GCC 6.1.